# How can you test which groups are in different distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, anova, group-differences

Let's say I have a some grouped data and I want to tell not only if the groups are all from the same distribution or not, but I also want to tell which groups are part of which distributions. ANOVAs tell you the former (right?) but I can't find anything that tells you the latter.

For example if I have 3 groups I would like to be able to classify them. For example, if we can reject the alternative hypothesis that groups 2 and 3 are from different distributions, classify them as being part of the first distribution. However if we can reject the null hypothesis that groups 1 and 2 are part of the same distribution (same with groups 1 and 3) then classify them as being part of the second distribution, and so on. Can you literally follow some algorithm like that comparing pairs of groups? I can see that being problematic if say group 1 and 2 are part of the same distribution, then so is 2 and 3. But groups 1 and 3 aren't.

To put this into context I'm rating pairs of photos by similarity (scale of 0.0-1.0) for multiple groups of photos. I want to pick the group of photos with the least mean similarity. But if the group with the least mean similarity seems like it is part of the same distribution as other groups. Then I could choose from those groups based on some other information. For example, I might then choose the group with the largest number of photos.

Comment: This is rather unclear. My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you reformulate the question so it can be answered.